# Android GridView getChildAt(0).findViewById() returns null

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview, baseadapter

I have a `GridView` with some items, I used a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`. each row shows a downloadable item, each row has an icon that show download progress.

*So I need to update this icon.*

For this update, I know that I can change the data and call `notifyDataChanged()` and the view will get updated, but this approach costs me a lot of changes and I don't want to do this.

So I tried to get a specific child from the `gridview`, find this icon and change the icon, But the returned view is null.

```
View v = mGridView.getChildAt(0);
if(v != null)
{
    ImageButton mDownloadButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.download_icon_button);
    if(mDownloadButton != null)
        updateDownloadIcon(mDownloadButton, intent.getIntExtra(DATA.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS, 0));
    else
        Log.e(TAG, "null image button");
}
```

`v` is not null but `mDownloadButton` is null.

any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_book_frag_item_layout, null);
        }

        mBookCoverImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookCoverID);
        mBookNameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookNameID);
        mBookWriterTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookWriterID);
        mBookOtherInfoTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookInfoID);
        mAudioImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.audio_image);
        mVideoImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.video_image);
        mDownloadButton = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_icon_button);
        mBookSize = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.download_size);
        mBookNameInCover = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bookNameInCover);

        sectionRow = getSectionRow(position);

        if(!mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmBookCover().equals(""))
        {
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmBookCover(), mBookCoverImageView);
            mBookNameInCover.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            mBookCoverImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.trans_icon);
            mBookNameInCover.setText(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmPostTitle());
        }

        mBookNameTextView.setText(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmPostTitle());
        mBookWriterTextView.setText(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmAuthorName());
        mBookOtherInfoTextView.setText(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getCatString());
        mBookSize.setText(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmEpubSize());

        if(isBookDownloaded(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).getmPostId()))
        {
            mDownloadButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.download_icon_90_100);
        }
        else
        {
            mDownloadButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.download_icon);
        }

        if(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).ismSound())
        {
            mAudioImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            mAudioImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if(mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]).ismVideo())
        {
            mVideoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            mVideoImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        if(mSelectsItems[sectionRow[0][0]][sectionRow[1][0]])
        {
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.allBookBaseLayout).setBackgroundResource(R.color.selection_color);
        }
        else
        {
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.allBookBaseLayout).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.book_view_one_column_item_background);
        }

        mDownloadButton.setOnClickListener(new DownloadClickListener(mDownloadButton, mHeaderInfo.get(sectionRow[0][0]).getmBooksInCat().get(sectionRow[1][0]), position));

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Update 2:**

My Adapter implements [StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapter](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders) and sometimes this give me duplicate id error so i set `mGridView.setId(-1);`

Comment: please post a getVIew method

Comment: i think `getChildAt(0)` returns **not a row** object. Need to debug and see that.

Comment: do you get the same error for `getChildAt(1)`? 0 might just return a header?

Comment: Are you using a standard `gridView` or a `StickyGridHeadersGridView`?

Comment: @M4rtini , I'm using `StickyGridHeadersGridView`. the `getChildAt(1)` is not null but it wont update the icon either!

Comment: @SergeyShustikov , I'm not sure i understand what are you saying.

Comment: Looking at the src of `StickyGridHeadersGridView` it seems like `getChildAt` returns the header view, not the row.

Comment: @M4rtini , Are you sure? i can see that it has `getHeaderAt()` for getting header and `StickyGridHeadersGridView ` does not Override `getChildAt `

Comment: I was confused by this line `View headerHolder = getChildAt(headerPosition);` from the src. but i think i found a solution. i'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getItemIdAtPosition` to compare the id against the id of headers. If it is not a header it should be the view containing your stuff.

```
long id = mGridView.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
if (id != StickyGridHeadersBaseAdapterWrapper.ID_HEADER) {
    // you now know that this item is not a header.
    View v = mGridView.getChildAt(i);
    if(v != null)
    {
        ImageButton mDownloadButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.download_icon_button);
        if(mDownloadButton != null)
            updateDownloadIcon(mDownloadButton, intent.getIntExtra(DATA.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS, 0));
        else
            Log.e(TAG, "null image button");
    }
}
```

They do this in the  [source](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/blob/master/Library/src/com/tonicartos/widget/stickygridheaders/StickyGridHeadersGridView.java#L849) of StickyGridHeadersGridView to find the headers, so it should work to find what is not the headers also.

Comment: It is really nice and works perfectly, but here is a little problem, the wrong icon will get updated because of headers. if 1 header is before clicked item the previous icon get updated. if there is 2 header before item 10 item 8 getting update. any suggestion?

Comment: @mehdok Start a loop from the first item, increase a counter at each item that is not a header. When the counter equals the position you should change, you're at the right item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the wrong id, are you sure R.id.download_icon_button is in the view?  If not you must add it.

Comment: please see the updated question, you can see the id is in the view.