# ExpandableListView getChildAt(id).findViewById() returns null

Tags: java, android

I've seen all questions that already post here...

[ExpandableListView getChildAt() return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204649/expandablelistview-getchildat-return-null)

[Android GridView getChildAt(0).findViewById() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955517/android-gridview-getchildat0-findviewbyid-returns-null)

But my problem not solve so please help me.

I just want to show textview background color in GroupView that expand and change previous one.

```
View view = expListView.getChildAt(id);
```

Its give me view everytime

```
textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_basket_name);
```

But findViewById() gives null sometimes

```
    View view = expListView.getChildAt(id);
    if (view != null) {
        textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_basket_name);
        if (textView != null) //Sometime gives null
            textView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gray));
    }
```

Comment: `getChildAt()` expects the index of the child, not an id. Are you sure you're passing the correct index?

Comment: Yes,I'm passing index.